# How do you prevent an application terminating if you close just one window?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I've trying to swtich between newly created forms but if I'm seen to be creating a new screen before I close the old one like below, the whole application will quit;

Inital Creation

```
static void Main()
{
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
Application.Run(new Login());
}
```

This login screen leads on to creating a new window where at the moment I'm hiding the screen to keep the application running;

```
new MainScreen(uID, this).Show();
this.Hide();
```

Within the MainScreen I have a 'Change User' button which means I need to create a new login screen, but the below code just exits the whole running application;

```
Login newLoginForm = new Login(this);
mainLoginForm.Close();
```

Am I designing this totally the wrong way or am I just not using the right method?! Any help would be great.

Comment: [Multiple users in Windows Forms](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8898718/719186) might be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you close the first login form your application exit from the Run(new Login())
so you should start with Run(new MainScreen()),
inside the constructor or Form_Load of this form call your login.

```
static void Main() 
{ 
    Application.EnableVisualStyles(); 
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 
    Application.Run(new MainScreen()); 
} 

public MainScreen()
{
    Login loginForm = new LoginForm();
    if(loginForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
        Application.Exit();
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: Hey Steve, thanks for your reply but I don't really get what you're saying. I want the login screen to be the first viewed screen.

Also, if I was to create a new MainScreen through the login screen and then was to close the MainScreen, the application will terminate even if the Login screen is still hidden.

Comment: Your **MainScreen** will be on screen only after the `Shown` event. So you could use the MainScreen constructor or the **MainScreen_Load** event to show your Login form and take the appropriate action on result (Application.Exit() if the user fails his/her credentials or continue with the application). Eventually your MainScreen will appear and the user will be able to change the current user again.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately to achieve this in WinForms, you need to manage the application and refcount the windows.

The MSDN documentation for [`Application.Run(ApplicationContext)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157901.aspx) there is sample code on how it could be achieved.

In WPF, you simply set the [`Application.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnLastWindowClosed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode.aspx).