# How can i make it so when i press a button it open a other form for login in c#

Tags: c#, windows, forms, authentication, windows-forms-designer

i am doing right now a Programm in c# and I want to make a login.
The Propem is when i click Login then i want to go to my next windows form window. I tried the code:

Login Form: Form2

Main Form: Form1

I tried a lot of codes but no on can help me.

```
                    this.Hide();
                    Form1 f1 = new Form1();
                    f1.ShowDialog();
                    this.Close();
```

I dont have any error messages but it open the same login menu.

Comment: Is this the code for the click event handler for a button on Form2, your login form?

Comment: This code doesn't appear to be opening the login form, it's opening the *main* form.  Where do you open the login form?  What do you mean by "it opens the same login menu"?  It's not really clear what you're trying to describe or demonstrate.

Comment: Sorry for the bad statement, I wanted to say that I have the login form and the code belongs to the login form. So I found the code in a Youtube tutorial and the person hats worked. Not at my place. Sorry for the bad description.

Comment: Yes It is from the Login form https://prnt.sc/op8bn9

Comment: @Bernhard: *"I have the login form and the code belongs to the login form"* - So what exactly is the problem?  The code you're showing hides whatever the current form is, creates an instance of `Form1`, displays that instance, then closes whatever the current form is.  Is that not what's happening in your program?  Please be thorough and specific about the problem description.

Comment: So the problem is I want to do it that way. When I hit the "Login" button, the main program will open. I can not say any more, I do not understand it exactly. But I hope now what I want. Here are screenshots to understand. Login form: https://prnt.sc/op8jv0
Main form:
https://prnt.sc/op8k5z

Comment: @Bernhard: So... This code opens the main form, and you want this code to open the main form?  Sorry, but you’re not describing a problem *at all*.  “I want to do it that way” doesn’t give us any information.  We can appreciate that there’s a language barrier here, but if anybody is going to be able to help you then you’re going to have to clarify the problem in the question you’re asking.

Comment: So I have the problem when I start the program and go in the login menu and I want to log in it does not bring me to the main menu but opens the login WIndow again. That's my problem.

Comment: I suggest you give your forms meaningful names. Instead of `Form1` rename it to `MainForm`, and instead of `Form2` rename it to `LoginForm`. Once you do that I think the problem may be a little more obvious; you're calling `ShowDialog()` on the main form and not the login form.

Comment: See [Multiple users in Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8898718/719186)

Comment: t does not work I have tested it and the login form has opened again. I'm just doing something wrong.
Screen Shot: https://prnt.sc/opaxcp

Comment: @Bernhard: The code you're showing us in the question opens an instance of `Form1`.  That's it.  If you have code in `Form1` that's doing something to open another login form, we don't know that.  Or if `Form1` is actually your login form and you've confused your forms, we don't know that.  All we know is what you're showing us.  This code opens an instance of `Form1`.

Answer (score 1):

To show another form you could use this piece of code :

```
  var mainForm = new Form1();
  mainForm.Show();
  this.Hide();
```

But with this code the Login form does not dispose, it just hides. it still remains in memory.

To get All open form you could use this command

```
 foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms)
 {
            //doSomthing
 }
```

In this loop, you have access to all open form's properties like Name, text, size and etc

Comment: Hello, when i use this code it opens the same window again. Do you know how to fix this? https://prnt.sc/op920k

Comment: I have the problems when I enter MainForm. Everything works fine when I use LoginForm.
https://prnt.sc/op98a5

Answer (score 0):

I think something is wrong, In the image that to put in your comment you did something like this :

```
foreach (Form from in Application.OpenForms)
{
  MainForm f1 = new MainForm();
  f1.ShowDialog();
  this.Close();
  this.Hide();
}
```

But why. you create an instance of the **MainForm** and after that, you close it!!!

Imagine you are in code section of **LoginForm** :

you should write the below code, behind of the **Login button of the (Form2)**.

```
Form1 f1 = new Form1();
f1.Show();
this.Hide();
```

Comment: Ok so whats the right code?

Comment: :) . I wrote it before. 

Form1 f1 = new Form1();
f1.Show();
this.Hide();

Comment: So idk anymore it opens the same login Form idk whyy

Comment: send me your sample code, i will check it  m.qafouri@gmail.com